# Issue while inserting dataframe value into Azure table storage in Python

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying to push my dataframe to Azure Table Storage using Python. But when I tried to insert a value, the values are getting jumbled up and also some of the records were not inserted into Azure. I dont know whether it is because of timing issue. Please find the code below.

```
for i in range(0,forecast.shape[0]):
partition_key=ticker+str(i)
stock_date=str(forecast.iloc[i]['ds'])
row_key=partition_key
stock_price=str(forecast.iloc[i]['yhat'])
companyname=str(forecast.iloc[i]['Company_Name'])
task = {'PartitionKey': partition_key, 'RowKey': row_key, 'StockPrice':stock_price, 'CompanyName':companyname,'Stock_date':stock_date}
v=table_service_actual.insert_entity("StockPricePrediction",task)
```

But in my Power BI when I tried to access the table storage:

[image]

But my actual dataframe looks like this:

[image]

Please help me in resolving the issue. I have also tried batch insertion.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is due to ordering. Since Azure uses sorted indices, it needs the partition key to be ordered. Consider having the sorted index as partition key